# JPA 2.0 IllegalArgumentException on existing entities and populated DB value

Tags: jpa

I am trying to return a string from a table based on a conditional ID (subid) from an already populated table. The query should return a list of type ItemDataPoint entity. In a JSF managed bean, the list will the  be iterated by a an enhaned for loop. If the word "Include" is found by the loop, the method will create a specific type of chart. In simpler terms, I want to return a string based the ID condition being met. I am getting:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException
(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.
completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx
(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2009)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set 
a parameter at position 2 which does not exist in this query string SELECT p FROM 
Itemdatapoint p JOIN p.series s WHERE s.master.item.subs.subid = :subid.
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.setParameterInternal(QueryImpl.java:925)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.setParameterInternal(QueryImpl.java:906)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.setParameter(EJBQueryImpl.java:469)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.setParameter(EJBQueryImpl.java:1)
at com.manaar.clientmods.gazprom.design3.data.facade.ItemdatapointFacade.
chartType(ItemdatapointFacade.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

The subid value of 2 exists if I run a native SQL query on the relevant parent table in the DB. Also the type of  the subid is an int in the main entity class, the JPQL Facade class and the managed bean.

The JPQL:

```
public List<Itemdatapoint> chartType (int subid) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Itemdatapoint p JOIN p.series s WHERE s.master.item.subs.subid = :subid");
    q.setParameter(subid, "subid");
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

The managed bean:

```
@Named(value = "reportBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ReportBean implements Serializable {

@Inject
private ItemdatapointFacade facade;

public String typeSwitch1() {
    subid = 2;
   chartType = facade.chartType(subid);
   for(Itemdatapoint e: chartType) {
       status = e.getSeries().getMaster().getStatus();
       if(status.equals("Include")) {
           return "line";
       }
   }
   return null; 
}
```

The xhtml page:

```
<p:chart type="#{reportBean.typeSwitch1()}" model="#{reportBean.subLineChart1}"/>
```

I also tried a non Join JPQL just from a single table:

```
public List<Itemdatapoint> noJoin (int subid) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Itemdatapoint p WHERE p.pointid = :subid");
    q.setParameter(subid, "subid");
    return q.getResultList();

}
```

Similar problem:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a
 parameter at position 2 which does not exist in this query string 
 SELECT p FROM Itemdatapoint p WHERE p.pointid = :subid.
```

I gather that IllegalArgumentException means that the selected entity does not exist or is not the correct type consistent with the query string in the facade class. But in my case the entity exists and the parameter is the correct type.

I would appreciate any help in understanding why i'm getting this error. Thank in advance!

**UPDATE**

Responding to the answer from lametaweb, I want to better understand the concept of JPA parameters.

*According to the JPA documentation, the first argument of the setParameter method is the parameter name or number. The second argument is the object that should be bound to the named parameter. Why does the following work without throwing Illegal ArgumentException?*

I tested an xhtml (web page):

```
<p:dataGrid id="rep1" columns="1" value="#{pageBean.itemPageList1}"  var="items1" rows="4">
<p:commandLink value="#{items1.itemname}" action="#{pageBean.showItem1}" ajax="false"/>                                    
</p:dataGrid>
```

The bean code:

```
  public ListDataModel<Sectionitem> getItemPageList1() {
    subid = 1;
    reportStatus = "Include";
    itemPageList1 = itemFacade.viewItems(subid, reportStatus);
    return itemPageList1;
}
```

The JPA facade:

```
public ListDataModel<Sectionitem> viewItems(int subid, String stat) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("select s from Sectionitem s JOIN s.subs c where c.subid = :subid AND s.status = :stat ORDER BY s.daterec");
 q.setParameter("subid", subid);
 q.setParameter("stat", stat);
    ListDataModel<Sectionitem> res
            = new ListDataModel<Sectionitem>(q.getResultList());
    return res;
}
```

Why is it in this case, the object exist but in my original case the subid object does not exist?

Comment: If the answer resolved your issue, please accept it. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Comment: Sorry I don't fully understand the concept behind the answer and I will be happy to accept it as soon as I do. Please see my updates to the question and comments to the answer. Many thanks

Comment: I didn't see the EDIT. You have to post a comment including '@lametaweb' string for me to know the edit. Ok. In your original answer you wrote: `q.setParameter(subid, "subid");` but in the last example you write `q.setParameter("subid", subid);`. The former is wrong, because `subid` is a parameter VALUE not a parameter POSITION, and the latter is OK. In the latter you pass an `int` as the second argument and Java wrap it automatically in an Integer using autoboxing. You can see all these overloaded methods [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?javax/persistence/Query.html).

Comment: Thank you for all the helpful explanations! It makes sense now. I was being careless and did not stick to the order of setParameter, first including position then value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking this method in your code:

```
setParameter(int position, Object value)
```

but you have to invoke this one instead:

```
setParameter(String name, Object value)
```

So your code should be:

```
q.setParameter("subid", Integer.valueOf(subid));
```

But, if you invoke:

```
q.setParameter(subid, "subid");
```

here the first parameter represents the position of the argument and the second the value for it. So you are passing a value of "subid" for the parameter in the second (2) position, which doesn't exist, because you only have one parameter in your JPQL query, hence the `IllegalArgumentException` exception.

Note: Why do you have a primitive type in your entity? Why not an Integer instead an int?

Comment: 602210 
 
 
 


       
 
I follow the logic of this very helpful answer but I would like to understand WHY in some cases the parameter object exists while it throws IAE in my original case as asked in the update to the question. In my second test case, I also have only one subid int parameter. So why does the first case throw IllegalArgumentException but the second test case works? Thank you! –